# How can I print the number of days elapsed to get the minimum number of record using awk?

Tags: awk

I need to print the number of days elapsed between the beginning date ($2 and $3) of the record ($4) until the record ($4) reaches minimum value for each unique ID ($1). In addition, I need to print the amount lost between the beginning value of the record and minimum value of the record ($4).

The data looks like this:

```
4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5  
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03   543.667  
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539  
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535  
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488  
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5  
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5  
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472
```

I need to look like this

```
4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5    3  11.5  
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03  543.667 3  11.5  
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539  3  11.5  
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535  3  11.5  
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488  3  17.5  
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5 3  17.5   
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5 3  17.5  
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472  3  17.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an GNU awk script like the following:

**script.awk**

```
FNR==NR { # first run, collect infos
        # split date and time, to generate a timestamp:
        split($2, d, "-")
        split($3, t, "[:]")
        ts=mktime( d[1] " " d[2] " " d[3] " " t[1] " " t[2] " " t[3] )

        if (!( $1 in start_T ) ) {
          start_T[ $1] = ts
          start_V[ $1] = $4
          min_V[ $1] = $4
          stop_T[ $1] = ts
        }
        if( $4 < min_V[ $1] ) {
            min_V[ $1] = $4
            stop_T[ $1] = ts
        }

        next; # skip next action block, during first run
      }

      { # this action block is used after first run
        printf("%s %5.0f %5.1f\n", $0, 
               (stop_T[$1] - start_T[$1]) / (60*60*24), # seconds per day
               start_V[$1] - min_V[$1] )
      }
```

It is used by providing the filename twice: `awk -f srcipt.awk yourfile yourfile`.

The first run collects info from the first filename given on the command line (the condition `FNR==NR` is true). The second run uses that information while processing the second filename given.

Comment: it works perfectly for the loss from the beginning of the record till the minimum value of the record. However, the number of days it takes to reach the minimum value of record ($4) is not working well. It just calculate the difference between the beginning and end record of the day.  I need to know the number of days ($2 &$3) it takes to reach the minimum value of the record ($4).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a 2-pass approach for this since your input is ordered by id so you can just print the result every time the id changes.

With GNU awk for mktime():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ dayNr = int( mktime( gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$2" "$3) ) / (24*60*60) ) }

$1 != prev {
    prtRows()
    begDayNr = dayNr
    begVal = minVal = $4
    prev = $1
}

{ rows[++numRows] = $0 }

$4 <= minVal {
    minVal = $4
    endDayNr = dayNr
}

END { prtRows() }

function prtRows() {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        print rows[rowNr], endDayNr - begDayNr, begVal - minVal
    }
    numRows = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5   3 11.5
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03   543.667   3 11.5
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539   3 11.5
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535   3 11.5
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488   3 17.5
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5   3 17.5
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5   3 17.5
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472 3 17.5
```